# C++ Function is Inaccessible

Tags: c++

I am wondering why this function is inaccessible.

The function:

```
class SERVER_DECL EventableObject
{

protected:
    void RemoveEvent(TimedEvent * ev);
};
```

Here is what I have:

```
Event * ReadyUp;
void Start()
{
    static uint8 Tick = 1;

    if(Tick == 1)
    {
        NormalMessage("Starting Event..");
    }
    EventableObject.RemoveEvent(this->ReadyUp); // Inaccessible
}
```

EventableObject.RemoveEvent(this->BattlefieldReadyUp); // Inaccessible

Is where I'm getting the error.

Comment: Change `protected:` to `public:` in your class definition; potentially make `RemoveEvent` static if that is what you intended.

Comment: please try to post code vaguely resembling C++

Answer (score 6):

It's inaccessible because it's `protected` instead of `public`.

`protected` means you can access it only from within the same, or a derived, class. Since you didn't indicate where your code was located, I'll just assume it is neither of those.

Comment: There's also the matter of doing ClassName.MethodName on a non-static method, I think.

Answer (score 1):

A `protected` function in a C++ can only be accessed by the class itself and derived classes, not outside the class, hence you're getting the error message that the function is inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's marked as `protected`, so it will not be visible to non-derived classes.

Second, it's not static, and it looks to me as though you are calling it as if it were.  Unless you have an object *instance* around named `EventableObject` you need an instance reference to call the function, i.e.,

```
EventableObject ev;
ev.RemoveEvent( this->ReadyUp );
```

Of course, that code makes little sense unless you had already added the event elsewhere, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

`EventableObject` is a type.

You need an object of that type to be able to call a member function.

Comment: Which still wouldn't work as the method is declared `protected`

Answer (score 0):

`EventableObject::RemoveEvent` is not declared `static`. This means you need an object of type `EventableObject` to call`EventableObject::RemoveEvent` on.

`EventableObject::RemoveEvent` is declared `protected`. This means it can only be called from within the class `EventableObject` itself and derived classes. Make it `public` if you have to call it from other locations.

Comment: Thanks all, I put public before and I received an error, but it wants to work now, lol. :/